# Filter/query list of users that not being blocked

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list off users in the app, I show that users list in an tableview, now I want to query that list of users to show only the users that have not being blocked by me as an user... So my database structure I'm thinking of is something like this;

- users

  - usersid-987545

    - name: String
    - description: String
    - blocked

      - userid-767438: true
  - usersid-767438

    - name: String
    - description: String

But this is a problem when I want to query list of users or later to search for a user with name and exclude a blocked user by that user... Whats a more scalable structure? Can you query a list of users and filter out the blocked users by that user?

Answer (score 0):

try to nest your data

DATABASE / Users / USERIDS / personal data
DATABASE / BLOCKS / USERID / blocked users
DATABASE / FRIENDS / USERID / listed friends

then
get the list of peeople blocked under the uid you are looking for (yours for example)
then
get all the friends
get all the blocked users
compare and exclude

Another solution would be to remove the blocked user from the friends list or to make a separate DATABASE / AUTHORIZED / USERID/ list of authorized people

Structuring data is really important and makes firebase so powerfull.

Comment: compare and exclude, I think thats to expensive on the client site or how you do that on mobile, I have an app in swift with a 1000 users and 6 blocked users ?